# scrapy : how to include hashtag in URL

Tags: character-encoding, scrapy, url-encoding

I have a URL of the form

```
url = "http://www.example.com/search.html#query=test"
```

When passing this to scrapy.Request as

```
yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_result)
```

and picking it up in `parse_result` like this

```
def parse_result(self, response):
    print(response.url)
```

the last bit in the string is always stripped, and is printed as follows

```
http://www.example.com/search.html
```

What do I need to do to be able to pick up the string in full from `response.url` meaning including the `#query=test` part? Tried to use the %23 code instead of the hashtag, but that is just being passed on as the number but not as a hashtag. And using

```
urllib.parse.quote(url)
```

creates a value error:

```
ValueError: Missing scheme in request
```

Comment: As far as I know, not even the browsers send that to the servers. It is used for client-side purposes. Do you really need to send it?

Comment: Take a look at the network tab from you browser dev tools and see what you are requesting from the server.

Comment: This is a real example, which you can copy-paste into a browser and it brings up the correct information: 
 [link]https://www2.deloitte.com/ch/en/misc/search.html#country=us#qr=accounting#p=2

Also, I did take a look at the network tab, but can't make heads nor tails out of it. There could be some jquery involved, but I don't understand how that could parse the string I send to the server (in the browser URL bar), i assume it's just being loaded as a reponse to the request submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Peter, the thing is that servers never get `hash` (or fragment identifier - that's how that piece is called). Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier "its processing is exclusively client-side".

In your case it means that there is some `JS` on webpage that will pick-up hash after page has been loaded, process it and bring a page to an actual state. Out of the box `Scrapy` is not capable of executing JS. So you have a few options here:

- Check `Network` tab of your browser and try to see if browser is making any XHR/Ajax requests. If yes, they may contain information you need to scrape.
- If browser doesn't make ajax/xhr requests then probably all required information is already in HTML response you got from server. It maybe in html tag data attributes, in hidden blocks and so on. Try to search around html response (do not use `Inspect Element` - that will show you html after it's been processed by JS. Instead, use `View page source` - that will show exactly what server has sent you).
- There are ways to execute JS with Scrapy - https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash but required advanced setup and more work than simple server-side processing.

Comment: What I don't understand, how can the fragment identifier be processed on the client side, if I simply type the URL into a "virgin" browser URL input? I can open any new browser window, with all the caches clear, type in the URL including the hashes, and voila, the correct response. See the link in my comment. And yes, further down the pipeline, I am using now Selenium, as I could not make it work with Splash.

Comment: "Virginity" of your browser has nothing to do with it :) What happens in most of cases is this:
- Browser sends request without fragment
- Server responds (doesn't even get fragment information)
- When page is loaded some piece of JS code from server will check if there is a fragment and will do more actions. In your case that JS issues following ajax request:
https://sp1004f46c.guided.ss-omtrdc.net/?q=%22accounting%22&page=2&sp_x_2=hide-in-search&sp_q_2=true&sp_q_required_2=-1&sp_e=3
That request contains information you see on the page.
- That JS will then rennder that data on the page